# How to read an integer from console without adding a newline in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, input, cin

I'm trying to read an integer from console in C++. The perk is I need the cursor to stay on same line as the it is.
To be more clear I want to get the values of a matrix and I need it to resemble a matrix shape on the screen. So any help is much appreciated.

P.S.: I'm on a Linux box if it's any relevant.

Comment: Well I've tried `\b` to no avail and I got nothing else.

Comment: getch() could work if you are working on a Windows machine. Probably not the best though.

Comment: Yeah it might. Although `getch()` reads only one character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appearance of the input data doesn't have so much to do with your program as with the actions
of the person entering the data. If they enter multiple numbers on one line,
then your program will read them all and not emit extra newlines.

This program should do it:

```
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    std::cout << "Type a 3x3 matrix\n";
    int matrix[3][3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        std::cin >> matrix[i][j];
}
```

When you this program, enter the numbers thusly:

1 <kbd>space</kbd> 2 <kbd>space</kbd> 3 <kbd>enter</kbd>
4 <kbd>space</kbd> 5 <kbd>space</kbd> 6 <kbd>enter</kbd>
7 <kbd>space</kbd> 8 <kbd>space</kbd> 9 <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: Nice. I really like simple and efficient solutions. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3):

Use ncurses or some other similar package for "terminal control".

Comment: Thanks, but this is for some noob who's got no clue of coding so I need to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: So, are you saying I should suggest a more complicated solution? It's the SIMPLEST solution you'll find - barring copying and pasting some code someone else wrote.

Comment: Note "ncurses" will give a `getch()` function. Bear in mind that whatever solution you choose to use, you WILL have to read a letter at a time and put it together into a number.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I just need to improvise.